# how Azure Table stores the data on physical disks?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

Azure table storage has this notion of partition key and row key. I wonder to know how data are stored on disk with regards to their partition keys? For example, in HBase each parition is stored as a separate file on disk an a region server is responsible of that. Is this the case for Azure Tables as well?

Answer (score 0):

This white paper goes into architecture details of Azure Storage. It also talks about the inner workings of partition layer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/11/20/windows-azure-storage-a-highly-available-cloud-storage-service-with-strong-consistency.aspx